# Two Particles systems attracted to same force field

Tags: particles, force-fields

So I have a NurbsPath that I turned into a Force field for a particle system, but I am trying to add an additional particle system to the scene but it is always attracted to the Force Field. Is there a way to make that particle emit by itself, without getting attracted to that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do that,
Just go to field weights tab in particle settings of that particle system and reduce the effect of the force field that you don't wan't to zero
[image: Screenshot]